# How to conditionally concatenate a range with VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, code, range

In my work, every end of the month I have to review data saved in spreadsheets like the image. The only data that interests me is to check the value of L column and obtain the data in the BS column. The column length is different for each file.  I´m trying to create VBA code to check row by row, and if in any column L is equal to -2, concatenate the data of that same row with the BS column. This string is saved to a variable declared as RefExc, which is shown on another page. I had looked at some answers to other similar questions, but couldn't find what I needed. I appreciate your help.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

debug.print will print out the result of each cycle to the immediate window in developer.

```
Sub MyConcat()

Dim RefExc As String
Dim c As Range
Dim x As Long

For Each c In Sheet1.Range("L2:L10")
If c.Value = -2 Then
For x = 6 To 73
If x <> 71 Then RefExc = RefExc & ", " & Sheet1.Cells(c.Row, x)
Next x
Debug.Print RefExc
End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I adapted it to complement the code and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this. If you need to concatenate in another column, then click on the first row of the cell where result will be and type the formula:

```
=IF(L2=-2,BS2&L2,"")
```

Then hold the bottom-right corner of the first cell and drag to the result cells. Screenshot is little different:

[image]

Comment: I need a VBA code because it is to complement a large code which opens all the files in a folder, extracts that information that I showed you in the image.